API, extension, script to connect google scholar to any latex IDE or overleaf?
I checked that there are ways to export from google scholar, or also with JabRef for example I make all the latex keys with google scholar format... but I was wondering... very often I find myself just going to google scholar and copy pasting a bib entry or doing a search in JabRef.
Has anyone found a way to make any latex compiler to use the references directly from google scholar? The standard for the key is quite reliable: 'authorLastNameYEARfirstWordInTitle' and there should be a way to implement such system.
Just to be sure, I am not saying exporting from google scholar as in Export google scholar citations to latex but doing it automatically.

That would probably be a security problem if they could

I'm not really sure I understand what the proposed workflow is. Is the idea that you type \cite{Jones2020Unicorns}, without already having this paper in your .bib file, and that this functionality would automatically extract the full entry from Google Scholar and add it to your .bib file?

@Marijn Exactly.

@daleif I don't really see why would that be a security problem, its a simple query.

As soon as it can go online it can download whatever, that is not secure
